# Changed email address attached to Google account - lost access to SO account

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, google, account-recovery

A while ago I removed my gmail address and attached another mail to my google account. However, I recently found out that this means I can't log in to my StackOverflow account! It treats the google account as a new one, and allowed me to register with it. However, I can't edit any account details because the mail address is already taken by the old account. How do I recover the old account?

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I don't think you can, however if you can prove both emails are yours you can ask to merge the accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did an [account merge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) as suggested in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156747/changed-email-address-attached-to-google-account-lost-access-to-so-account?rq=1#comment451597_156747):

> I don't think you can, however if you can prove both emails are yours you can ask to merge the accounts.

Thanks!

Comment: What? What account restore?'

Comment: @daylight I was referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).