# Can someone merge my two accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

Over 48 hours ago I submitted a *Contact Us* item requesting help.
Here are the details.
I have a SO account which I've lost because I changed the email address associated with my google account -- which it is tied to: user:255243 (screen name - daylight).

To get on to SO I had to create a new account (user:2883178 screen name - daylight) that I used to do the *Contact Us*.

Wait, before you quickly respond that this is a duplicate, here is the issue:

**I cannot access the email address for the original account because it is on a domain I no longer have access to**: dj@daylightcomputers.com so I cannot retrieve an email.

That means **I cannot follow the Merge Two Accounts instructions**

1. How can I resolve this?
2. Is there any way to resolve this?
3. Why is does this occur?  My account should be tied to my Google Account not the associated email address, right?
4. Why did I have to sign up for an account on meta.stackoverflow.com when I already have an account on stackoverflow.com?  Here at meta SO my account is (user:241669 screen name daylight)  What?

Also, please note, when I submitted the original request to the Contact Us I did not receive any auto-responder (via email) that the issue had been received nor can I find any place in my SO account that shows my *Contact Us* issue was submitted. That makes it very difficult for a user to know if the issue was properly received by SO.

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/contact and choose the Account Merge option.

Comment: JonW, That is exactly what I did over 48 hours ago. Will it work if I do it again?

Comment: @daylight If you already did it, then there's no *need* to do it again.  Just be patient.

Answer (score 2):

We replied to you on Tuesday, asking for further verification, with no response. Note that the instructions require you to annotate *at least* one of your accounts before we merge. I know this is probably frustrating, but believe it or not we do occasionally get folks trying to dodgy stuff... It's worth a little bit of extra effort to prevent mistakes.

For now, I've merged your accounts, after verifying that the same Google account had been attached to both emails. This is a reasonably common problem; see: [Changed email address attached to Google account - lost access to SO account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156747/changed-email-address-attached-to-google-account-lost-access-to-so-account)

Comment: Can you please merge [this account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811) with [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859)? Please? ;)

Comment: What's that? You want to transfer ownership of all of your posts to me? Well...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: What, choosing Jon Skeet is too mainstream now? :-)

Comment: Thank you for taking care of it. It is possible that my spam filter removed your request so that I never saw it.  I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: No problem, @daylight - but you might want to whitelist stackexchange.com / stackoverflow.com addresses so they don't get caught by the filters in the future. Makes it really hard to provide support otherwise...